# Wordpress site - theme file deleted and images uploaded

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I just discovered today that a file from my Wordpress website was deleted overnight which caused the site to no longer load. The file that was deleted was a functions.php file found in the current theme folder:

wp-content/themes/enfold/functions.php

In addition to this 4 new jpg files were also created in the wp-includes/images directory as follows:

/wp-includes/images/geo.jpg

/wp-includes/images/save.jpg

/wp-includes/images/magic.jpg

/wp-includes/images/links.jpg

These are not real jpg files as they don't open, but looking at them with a text editor reveals text and additional PHP code.From looking at the PHP code it looks like it's trying to inject some spam/advertising links into my Wordpress POSTS.

I've recently reset the passwords for everything that I could find, including passwords for FTP, mysql , DB ,  Cpanel , all Wordpress user logins.

I've used the Theme Authenticity Checker plugin to scan for any malware with the themes and it hasn't detected anything.

I'm at a bit of a loss here - is there some log file or method I can use to determine how the "hacker" is gaining access to my Wordpress site (I use a security plugin to lockout invalid logins etc) so I can close whatever loophole they're exploiting?

Comment: sounds more like there is an image upload somewhere they are exploiting..go back to core and re-evaluate all your plugins/ themes, make sure your wp is updated. Images can be actually quite hard to guard against fake pictures, you can try resize on them in your upload script. google it. But of course it could be the server was breached, etc....